# Mocking PDOException class fails to respond

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing a unit test to mimic the dreaded MySql has gone away error, but I'm having an issue having my mock object respond correctly. Maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

```
private function getMockGoneAway()
{   
    $e = $this->getMockBuilder('PDOException')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods([
            'getMessage',
            'getCode',
        ])  
        ->getMock();

    $e->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getMessage')
        ->willReturn('SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away');

    $e->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getCode')
        ->willReturn('HY000');

    return $e;
}
```

This is the test. The issue is that no matter where it happens, I cannot get the mock exception to return the intended result from getMessage or getCode.

```
public function testBeginTransactionGoneAway()
{       
    // get a mock PDO object that overrides beginTransaction method
    $mock_pdo = $this->getMockPdo(['beginTransaction']);

    // grab a mock gone-away exception object
    $mock_gone_away_exception = $this->getMockGoneAway();

    die("MSG: ".$mock_gone_away_exception->getMessage());

    // setup mock pdo responses
    $mock_pdo->expects($this->once())
        ->method('beginTransaction')
        ->will($this->throwException($mock_gone_away_exception));

    $this->db->replaceConnection($mock_pdo);
    $this->db->begin();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured this out. The base exception class declares getMessage and getCode to be final. For some reason PHPUnit doesn't let you know that it can't override these methods. So like with the mock PDO class, you need to manually mock the PDOException class too.

```
class MockPDOException extends \PDOException
{
    public function __construct($msg, $code) {
        $this->message = $msg;
        $this->code = $code;
    }   
}
```

Now you can imitate the exception correctly

```
$mock_gone_away_exception = new MockPDOException('SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away','HY000');

// setup mock pdo responses
$mock_pdo->expects($this->once())
    ->method('beginTransaction')
    ->will($this->throwException($mock_gone_away_exception));
```

So that was fun. Learning more about PHPUnit every day. Comments on why this is a bad idea are welcome.